# Error : "could not find or load main class \lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar"

Tags: cassandra

While running 'cassandra.bat' file on Windows, I am getting the error "could not find or load main class \lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar. Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your directory structure is correct, check for the file jamm-0.3.0.jar under lib directory.

Comment: yes.. the directory structure is correct. jamm-0.3.0 is present in lib directory.

Comment: I downloaded the cassandra binaries again and then tried running cassandra.bat. This time it ran without the above error.